# Pands: Creating dataframe based on keywords from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dictionary where key is model name and values are keywords. I want to filter every row in a column that string contains one of the keywords that are in the values of dictionary.
Matching should be case insensitive.

Dictionary looks like this:

```
{'J7 2017': [' J730F', 'amoled'], 'J5 2017': ['J530', 'TFT']}
```

data frame looks like:

```
           name  
0  SCREEN SAMSUNG FULL AMOLED  
1  SCREEN SAMSUNG J7 J730F 2017
2  WYŚWIETLACZ LCD + DIGITIZER SAMSUNG J5 2017 (J530)
3  3 colors SCREEN LCD SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 TFT
4  LG K10 K410 K420N K430
```

As a result i want to have model name [key] stored in separate data frame with with all rows that had my keyword

so the output would be:

```
dfJ72017:

         name  
0  SCREEN SAMSUNG FULL AMOLED  
1  SCREEN SAMSUNG J7 J730F 2017

dfJ52017:
             name  
    0  WYŚWIETLACZ LCD + DIGITIZER SAMSUNG J5 2017 (J530) 
    1  3 colors SCREEN LCD SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 TFT
```

And do it for all keys and values in dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `'|'.join` here is for regex `OR`:

```
d = {'J7 2017': [' J730F', 'AMOLED'], 'J5 2017': ['J530', 'TFT']} 

dfs = {k: df[df['name'].str.contains('|'.join(v))] for k, v in d.items()}

print (dfs)

{'J7 2017':                            name
0  SCREEN SAMSUNG FULL AMOLED  
1  SCREEN SAMSUNG J7 J730F 2017, 'J5 2017':   name
2  WYŚWIETLACZ LCD + DIGITIZER SAMSUNG J5 2017 (J...
3          3 colors SCREEN LCD SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 TFT}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution is great and it works like a charm. I'm trying to figure out the code and i have one question.

Comment: Hi, your solution is great and it works like a charm. I'm trying to figure out the code and i have one question.
I've tried to use others boolean indexing's such as ~ but when i replace '|'.join in your code for '~'.join the result is still the same, please help me understand why and how to use other indexes?

Comment: @user732954 if need different masks use `df[~df['name'].str.contains('|'.join(v))]`

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to use another method in this dict comprehension?
Such as:
df.nlargest(5, 'DIFFRENT COLUMN NAME')

Comment: @user732954 - do you need replace `df[df['name'].str.contains('|'.join(v))]` by `df.nlargest(5, 'col name')` ?

Comment: @user732954 or chain it by `df[df['name'].str.contains('|'.join(v))].nlargest(5, 'col name')` ? First filter data by values and then get 5 top rows

Comment: First one gave me syntax error, but second solution worked out great. Thanks again!